# Working and grouping data from csv files - using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

In relation to this topic [Convert data from CSV to list of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268730/convert-data-from-csv-to-list-of-dict/69268810?noredirect=1#comment122431047_69268810), I would like to ask a few additional questions regarding the processing of data contained in the CSV file.

1. How best to rename values for "school_subject" with condition: where term = 2 and school_subject == "foreign language" - I would like rename "foreign language" to "oth_lang" - I am looking the best performance way to do this. I could make a loop and change the value, but it is the easiest way but not the best,

Partial answer for 1 question.

```
df.loc[(df['school_subject'].str.contains('foreign language')) & (df['term'] == '2'), 'school_subject'] = 'oth_language'
```

Is it possible to put another group of conditions in the same "loc" for example to `(df['school_subject'].str.contains('Informatics'))`? In current version I need to create 2 lines of similar code with next conditions.

2. @jezrael helped me create the correct "query" for grouping data. How can we:

   - exclude data using code from linked code? I need separate data by term?
   - how to join data - ex. the students from term 1 and 2 I would like joining like a one year

Thank you for help and potential example of code.

Comment: Can you share an example of what the data structure you are working with looks like in the body of this question?

Comment: It is the same data like in the linked topic